# Partial and total concentration in solutions

Tags: solutions, concentration

> The total pressure of gas mixture equals the sum of partial pressures of its components.

Can this rule be true for liquid concentration?
I.e. can we say: the total concentration of mixture is equal to the sum of partial concentrations of its components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true and false.

For example: 
1 Solution with 1mol/L of NaCl and 1mol/L of KBr.
The total concentration of salts is 2mol/L.

But the ions concentration are:

Na+ 1mol/L
K+ 1mol/L
Cl- 1mol/L
Br- 1mol/L

Is it clear?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but can we say the total concentration of the reactants equals the total concentration of products ,

Comment: Can you give me an example eg a reaction?

Comment: @OmarAlBahra You *can* always say that the total concentration of reactant atoms equals the total concentration of product atoms. You ***cannot*** always say that the total concentration of reactant species equals the total concentration of product species: sometimes this is true, but often it is not.

Comment: Thanks @Brian ,like this reaction : ch3cooc2h5 +h2o give ch3cooh +c2h5oh

Comment: @OmarAlBahra Yes, that is a reaction where, technically, the total concentrations of reactants and products are equal, because the number of moles of reactants equals the number of moles of products.  However, water as a reactant/product is a unique case, since its concentration is so high the [change due to reaction is negligible](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42008/why-is-water-not-part-of-the-equilibrium-constant). So, for practical experimental purposes, the total concentration of products would be considered greater than that of reactants.