# What is the pKa of the O-17 hydronium ion?

Tags: acid-base, ph

At low concentrations of a conjugate acid/base pair in aqueous solutions, the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation gives a good approximation of the ratio of acid and base:

$$ \frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{AH}]} = 10^{(\mathrm{pH} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a})\tag{1}}$$

If I add a low concentration of $\ce{[^17O]}$ water to an aqueous solution with pH of zero, I would think the heavy water behaves similarly to the solvent. In fact, we don't even have to add heavy water because at natural abundance, 0.038% of oxygen atoms are isotope 17.

I am wondering what the ratio of hydronium to water is for the heavier isotope. For the solvent, it is about 1:55. If it is the same for the heavier isotope, the reaction

$$\ce{[^17O]H2O + H+ <=> [^17O]H3O+}\tag{2}$$

or

$$\ce{[^17O]H2O(aq) + H3O+(aq) <=> [^17O]H3O+(aq)  + H2O(l)}\tag{3}$$

would have a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of -1.74. However, the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of water is [sometimes quoted as 0](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9847).

So is the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{[^17O]H2O}$ different than that of $\ce{[^16O]H2O}$, or do I have to use two different values, depending on whether the solvent is something else or part of the acid/base reaction in question. Surely, $\ce{[^17O]H2O}$ and $\ce{[^16O]H2O}$ have similar $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values in DMSO, where the equilibrium reaction shown above (3) would be written slightly differently and would have an equilibrium constant very close to one:

$$\ce{[^17O]H2O(DMSO) + H3O+(DMSO) <=> [^17O]H3O+(DMSO)  + H2O(DMSO)}\tag{4}$$

Comment: I would use -1.74 for O-17 water and 0 for O-16 water if O-16 is the bulk solvent, because it seems like those are the values that would give the right results for any relevant calculation, but I'm not confident that's the correct general answer

Comment: The difference between 0 and -1.74 has nothing to do with isotopes. It has to do with what we define as the unit quantities to put into the equilibrium constant. If a unit corresponds to the pure solvent fir water, then the $pK_a$ is zero. If the unit is 1 molar concentration for water as for other species, then pure water is about 55 units and from the logarithm of that we end with -1.74. It's a confusing convention, but at lease we can say that either way using oxygen-17 should have hardly any effect.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I agree, but this specific example shows that there are cases where the value of -1.74 does make sense. If you switched the concentrations of heavy and light water (i.e. traces of O-16 water in bulk O-17 water), you would get zero for O-17 and -1.74 for O-16 with the commonly used standard state definitions (or say that in this case, the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of O-16 water is not defined, but the Kw is).